# WiFi not available on Lenovo Thinkpad E15 Gen 4 / Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, thinkpad

I installed Ubuntu "22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)" on my ThinkPad E15 Gen 4, but the WiFi does not work.

I used the command on this link
[My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

to create this wifireless-info.txt
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/jNM99GhPzD/

Is this enough to find out why I cannot have a wireless connection?

########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 19 Apr 2023 15:10 CEST +0200

Booted last: 19 Apr 2023 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

###### release

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

###### kernel

Linux 5.19.0-40-generic #41~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Mar 31 16:00:14 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

###### desktop

Ubuntu

###### lspci

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:50b1]
Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4853]

04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barcelo [1002:15e7] (rev c2)

###### lsusb

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:4853 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:550a Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:2146 Acer, Inc Integrated RGB Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

###### PCMCIA card info

###### rfkill

1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

###### secure boot

SecureBoot disabled

###### lsmod

wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    32768  2 wmi_bmof,think_lmi

###### interfaces

###### ifconfig

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback  brd 
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]> brd 
inet 192.168.178.68/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
valid_lft 863803sec preferred_lft 863803sec
inet6 2a02:678:640:3b00:216:e217:d7f4:e992/64 scope global temporary dynamic
valid_lft 3309sec preferred_lft 909sec
inet6 2a02:678:640:3b00:5491:1bd7:a921:afcc/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
valid_lft 3309sec preferred_lft 909sec
inet6 fe80::9e3f:13bd:1df8:8d41/64 scope link noprefixroute
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

###### iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

###### route

default via 192.168.178.1 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp metric 100
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp2s0 scope link metric 1000
192.168.178.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.68 metric 100

###### resolv.conf

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search fritz.box

###### network managers

Installed:

```
NetworkManager
```

Running:

root         660       1  0 13:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

###### NetworkManager info

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.19.0-40-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:02:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       c06b2b99-9ca3-3375-9950-1a32737697fb
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.178.68/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.178.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.178.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.178.1, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.178.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          fritz.box
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.178.255
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 864000
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name = fritz.box
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        expiry = 1682773615
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        ip_address = 192.168.178.68
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        next_server = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        ntp_servers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       routers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2a02:678:640:3b00:216:e217:d7f4:e992/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         2a02:678:640:3b00:5491:1bd7:a921:afcc/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fe80::9e3f:13bd:1df8:8d41/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::9a9b:cbff:fe9e:ea32
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 2a02:678:640:3b00::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 2a02:678:640:3b00::/56, nh = fe80::9a9b:cbff:fe9e:ea32, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::9a9b:cbff:fe9e:ea32, mt = 100
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fd00::9a9b:cbff:fe9e:ea32
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = fd00::9a9b:cbff:fe9e:ea32
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_ntp_servers = fd00::9a9b:cbff:fe9e:ea32
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   c06b2b99-9ca3-3375-9950-1a32737697fb | Wired connection 1

###### NetworkManager.state

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

###### NetworkManager config

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

###### NetworkManager profiles

###### Netplan config

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager

###### iw reg get

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

###### iwlist channels

lo        no frequency information.

enp2s0    no frequency information.

###### iwlist scan

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

###### module infos

###### module parameters

###### /etc/modules

###### modprobe options

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi 
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) 
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

###### rc.local

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

###### pm-utils

###### udev rules

###### dmesg

[ 7354.127364] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852bu_fw.bin
[ 7354.127478] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852bu_config.bin
[ 7354.331137] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Down
[ 7357.507038] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[ 7357.507078] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############